# How to redirect php file without .php

Tags: php, rest

I have an API `list.php` it will produce a response like

```
[
 {
  id: "10000",
  name: "John Doe",
  designation: "Android Developer",
  mobile: "5550088966",
  email: "john@doe.com"
},
{
  id: "10001",
  name: "Foo Bar",
  designation: "UI Designer",
  mobile: "5550158556",
  email: "foo@bar.com"
 }
]
```

and if I call the API like `list.php/10000` it will only return the user with the id like

```
{
  id: "10000",
  name: "John Doe",
  designation: "Android Developer",
  mobile: "5550088966",
  email: "john@doe.com"
}
```

I have written some code for my `.htaccess` file to call the API like `list` and `list/10000`

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

but only the `list` working but `list/10000` not working how can I solve this

this is the php script

```
<?Php
// Create database authentication and connection
$dbHost = "localhost";
$dbName = "id10693574_android";
$dbUsername =   "id10693574_aseemsalim";
$dbPassword =   "aseemsalim@12";

$connection =   mysqli_connect($dbHost,$dbUsername,$dbPassword,$dbName);
$where='';
$url=$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
// print_r($url);exit;
$url_array=explode('list.php',$url);
//print_r($url_array);
//exit;
if(!empty($url_array['1']))
{
    $slashid=$url_array[1];
    $id=substr($slashid,1);
    $where= "WHERE id=$id";
}
//exit;
$sql    =   "select * from employees $where";

$results= mysqli_query($connection,$sql);

$response = array();

while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($results)){
    array_push($response,array('id'=>$row['id'],'name'=>$row['name'],'designation'=>$row['designation'],'mobile'=>$row['mobile'],'email'=>$row['email']));
}
if($response){
echo json_encode($response);
}
else{
   echo json_encode(null); 
}

mysqli_close($connection);
     ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for this URL:

```
https://restapiaseem.000webhostapp.com/api/employees/list.php
```

It works:

```
 RewriteEngine on 
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^(.*)/list/(.*)$ $1/list.php?id=$2 [L,QSA]
 RewriteRule ^(.*)/list $1/list.php
```

You can also test here: https://htaccess.madewithlove.be

Comment: ```https://restapiaseem.000webhostapp.com/api/employees/list.php``` php code added above

Answer (score 0):

Can you try `RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)\/([0-9]+)\/?$ list.php?param=$1&param2=$2 [NC]`

You can then call `$_REQUEST` `['param']` and `['param2']` to access your API

Answer (score 0):

You ought to be abto to use the following

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^list/([0-9]+)/?$ /api/employees/list.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
```

which would allow you to use a url such as:

```
https://restapiaseem.000webhostapp.com/list/1000
```

This would mean that you can access `$_GET['id']` and use that in whatever sql query you have that generates the recordset